# Should I enable jumbo frame size of 9000 bytes for my NICs?

Tags: networking, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet

Should I enable a jumbo frame size of 9000 bytes for my NICs if I am running a gigabit network? Will it increase performance?

For this scenario: PC to router to PC, on a gigabit network.

Comment: This is hard to say without knowing the details of your network.

Comment: I wonder if this has changed in 2019 and beyond. As far as I've seen, all recently 1Gbps devices support jumbo frames, but Wi-Fi devices do not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The deal is this: If **everything** on your network supports jumbo frames, than by all means, enable it and test. If your NICs are reasonable, and your cabling is without serious problems, you might see an increase in performance. How much? It depends on a lot of factors: how many computers, how good/fast is your switch, network traffic patters, etc. But generally not more than **10% percent** in a typical home network or small office network environment.

Here are some testing results from [boche.net](http://www.boche.net/blog/index.php/2011/01/24/jumbo-frames-comparison-testing-with-ip-storage-and-vmotion/):

[image: Jumbo Frame Testing Results]

### Warning

If you have at least one device on your network that does **not** support jumbo frames (network printer, SIP phone, etc.) then you cannot use jumbo frames at all. Otherwise you won't be able to talk to that device.

Comment: It can improve a good bit more depending on the nature of your traffic - a home network is unlikely to see better than 10% improvement due to usage pattern.

Comment: @Ram: True. I'll extend my answer a bit.

Comment: I have a small ioMega NAS box that actually gets almost double the throughput using jumbo frames, but that's because the large frames allow more data transfer with lower CPU utilization (it has a low-end ARM-compatible cpu)

Comment: this mean enable it on the router too ?

Comment: @Rushino: Yes of course.

Comment: I think it's possible for switches to enable Jumbo Packets on a per-port basis. Not 100% sure, but I've enabled Jumbo Frames in my network, and all my IoT devices still work.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested 1G and 10G.  1500 byte packets allows you to achive nearly 100% utilization of 1G (100MBytes/s).  On 10G hardware, with 1500 byte packets, you see 1G speed.  If you increase to the max (9600 bytes), you get 450MBytes/s (of course you need striped SSDs at both ends to do this).

Hardware: Dell Precision workstations T3500, T5500, Mellannox cards, SFP+ copper direct connect 10G cable, running Windows 10 at one end, Windows Server 2012 at the other end.

Answer (score 0):

It is false - you can have a device that do not support jumbo frames and it will work as it works to me – I have home gigabit network with a network printer and all work perfectly – switch simply chopping the jumbo frame into the chunks able to be accepted by the 100M network printer. The author obviously speaks story out of his own experience.

Comment: Both of you are probably right. Some setups will allow jumbo packets to be fragmented. Some others will not. Here's what Jeff Atwood had to say on the matter: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/the-promise-and-peril-of-jumbo-frames.html . Anyway, there's nothing wrong in just *trying*. If it doesn't work, well, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The often overlooked purpose of jumbo frames is to reduce the CPU overhead of making and reassembling packets. This benefit can vary a substantially from one machine to the next, servers with fancy task offloading network cards don't see any benefit for the sender and maybe 15% for the receiver. But a low cost system with a simple network interface has the CPU do all of the work and some have reported a 3:! change in CPU load with jumbo packets.

I don't have a way to test Jumbo on my current network, but I have found the standard 1500B frames on my consumer-level desktop and laptop, require around 1Ghz of 1 CPU core to saturate a 1Gb connection. (So one core operates at 30% with a 3.4Ghz CPU or at 50% with a 2.0Ghz [laptop] CPU, and it basically runs my old 1Ghz NAS near fully loaded.)

Jumbo is also reported to reduce processing load on routers, switches, and firewall packet inspection and port forwarding.

A place where the CPU load may matter is in cluster situations where that network load on the CPU directly cuts into compute resources. (when the whole point of making a compute cluster is to get a net gain is useful work.)
Put another way, it is very plausible that the compute power used to receive results computed on another cluster node is nearly as much CPU load as directly computing the results locally, making the deal pretty pointless, but jumbo frames could change that situation from break even into 3:1 leverage.
It's a pretty narrow example but I can't think of a casual desktop use that would be substantially effected, because most personal computers have a huge proportion of idle
CPU and network time every minute. (As opposed to a computation that loads the system to 100% continuously for several days so even 5% can be multiple hours [and electricity] saved.)